# CDHtmlDialog, window.external, and XP (RTM)

Tags: c++, mfc

The Javascript hooks that I've defined for a CDHtmlDialog in MFC (using BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP..END_DISPATCH_MAP) are not available in XP (RTM.. no service packs allowed), since "window.external" (where the hooks live) appears to be undefined. IE is in its default configuration, except for minimizing its security settings.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Any use? http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1233926.htm

Comment: I already saw this. They're having an entirely different problem. It is also in IE7, which is only installable on SP2. I don't have my problem in SP2. Thanks, though.